# PrtScn takes pictures of all desktops at the same time

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

How can I specify which screen I want to take a picture of? I don't want to crop the result in a photo editor.

Comment: Alt-PrtScn will take a copy of the current program *window*, not sure if there is one for the current *screen*.

Comment: win+shift+s allows you to paint a rectangle that will become a screenshot.

Comment: Maybe `Full-Screen Snip` from `Windows key + shift`-`S` (Snip & Sketch) menu  (or the new Screen snip button in the Action Center)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL + ALT + PrtScn should do this, although there has to be an open window on the desktop that you want to screenshot. 
[source](https://www.sikich.com/insight/simple-screenshots-with-dual-monitors/)